# snowflake connector errors ProgrammingError 100078 (22000)

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When i am trying to load data from s3 to snowflake using python script i am getting the following error,

```
String '$METADATA$FILENAME' is too long and would be truncated
  File '#######', line 1, character 1
  Row 1, column $METADATA$FILENAME
```

I am trying to store the original file name in the table. For that i am using `$METADATA$FILENAME` key word. In the table this column define with   `VARCHAR(16777216)` datatype with full length.
Is there any way to solve this issue

Comment: can you please show the code you are using to do this - and provide an example of one of the filenames?

Comment: Examples would be helpful, and also what you have tested so far.  Does your filename go beyond 16777216 characters and/or your values greater than 16MB for the column?

Comment: Sorry guys i cannot share the code. @Suzy Lockwood yes my values greater than 16mb for the column and it not go beyond the 16777216

Comment: @YohanNeranga Snowflake's maximum length for VARCHAR is 16MB (uncompressed) as noted in the docs: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#data-types-for-text-strings

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the python script . Next time onwards please share your code too.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import subprocess
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import logging
from logging import getLogger


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("my_app").config('spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage', False).getOrCreate()

sc=spark.sparkContext
hadoop_conf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", " ") # Fill your values here
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "")  # Fill your values here

logging.basicConfig(
        filename=v_log,
        level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = getLogger(__name__)

sfOptions = {
    "sfURL": "sfcsupport.snowflakecomputing.com",
    "sfAccount": "", # Fill your values here
    "sfUser": "", # Fill your values here
    "sfPassword": "", # Fill your values here
    "sfDatabase": "", # Fill your values here
    "sfSchema": "PUBLIC",
    "sfWarehouse": "", # Fill your values here
    "sfRole": "", # Fill your values here
    "parallelism": "64",
    "awsAccessKey": hadoop_conf.get("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId"),
    "awsSecretKey": hadoop_conf.get("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey"),
    "tempdir": "s3n://<pathtofile>"  # Fill your values here
}




SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"


df = spark.read.option("delimiter", ",").csv(
    "s3n://<pathtofile>", header=False)  # Fill your values here
df.show()
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```